# Is there any way I can enlarge a stimulus in #psychopy without losing image quiality?

Tags: psychopy

I'm importing my stimulus from a folder. I would like to make them bigger *the actual image size is 120 pix (height) x 170 pix (width). I've tried to double the size by using this code in the PsychoPy Coder:

stimuli.append(visual.ImageStim(win=win, name='image', **units='cm', size= [9, 6.3],**

(I used the double number in cms) but this distorts the image. Is it any way to enlarge it without it distorting, or do I have to change the stimuli itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer what Michael said in the comment: no, if you scale an image up, the only way of guessing what is in between pixels is interpolation. This is what psychopy does and what ANY software would do. To make an analogy: take a picture of a distant tree using your digital camera. Then scale the image up using all kinds of software. You won't suddenly be able to see the individual leaves since the software had no such information as input.

If you need higher resolution, put higher resolution images in your folder. If it's simple shapes, you may use built-in methods such as `visual.ShapeStim` and it's variants: `visual.Polygon`, `visual.Rect` and `visual.Circle`. Psychopy can scale these shapes freely so they always stay sharp.